# Can't import TouchActions in selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, import, modulenotfounderror

and thanks in advance.
I have a problem with selenium. I can't import the TouchActions implementation in any way. I tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
#imp. keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
#imp. touch actions
from selenium.webdriver.common.touch_actions import TouchActions
#imp. time
import time
```

and it doesn't work because it gives me the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver.common.touch_actions'` ERROR. I have installed pip3 and everything else from selenium seems to work fine (like It makes me import ActionChains).
I do not know what to do....

Comment: Did you try to import the whole module? If it still doesn't work, meaning you didn't add selenium to your environment. Use pip install selenium

Comment: I am sure selenium is installed into my environment. Everything else form selenium works fine. How can I import the whole module?

Comment: import selenium

Comment: i did it. I said everything else is working… just that implementation seems to not work. I will just use appium at this point, i don’t even know anymore